# Angular 4 json object from c# rest service

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rest, service

I have a simple service which is sending a json string into a json component. How can I access individual elements of json in the component. The response is as follows.

```
GetExamResult:
"{"Question":"This is the Question","Answer1":"This is 
Answer1","Answer2":"This is Answer2","Answer3":"This is 
Answer3","Answer4":"This is Answer4","Correct":1}"
```

I have tried 
    this.answer1 = data[0].answer1;

but it is giving the variable as undefined.

Trying like this

```
getData(){
    this.httpClient.get('someservice')
    .subscribe(
      (data:any[]) => {
        this.ques1 = data[0].GetExamResult.Question1;
        console.log(this.ques1);

  }
)
```

Comment: You can use JSON.parse, after that you should use something like this: obj['GetExamResult']['Answer1']

Comment: @Nour, this is just wath I said before you... Do you read the answers before you write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.count);
// expected output: 42

console.log(obj.result);
// expected output: true
```

in your case, for example:

```
var getExamResult = '{ "Question": "This is the Question", "Answer1": "This is Answer1", "Answer2": "This is Answer2" }';
var obj = JSON.parse(getExamResult);

console.log(obj.Answer1);
// expected output: This is Answer1
console.log(obj.Answer2);
// expected output: This is Answer1
```

Comment: In the above json example how can I get only the question part because it is under GetExamResult. Thanks

Comment: I added the response to your question in the code. I hope the can help you. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

data is an object, you can directly access as

```
 this.answer1 = data.answer1;
```